# I need to display only numerical value from a varchar2 datatype column without using any regex

Tags: sql, oracle

Table name `SAMP_TAB` - it has only one column `COL` of datatype `varchar2` - with data like this:

```
COL
----
1234
abcd
098
12wer
345
```

These are the above sample values in that column.

Now I want to write a query which will return only numeric values from this column.

Desired output:

```
1234
098
345
```

I want to write that query without using any regex.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 12c R2 or later (and you should be) you can use the built-in function `validate_conversion()` which is a safe way of determining whether a value can be converted to another datatype. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

Like this:

```
select * from samp_table
where validate_conversion(col as number) = 1
/
```

This approach has a major advantage over solutions using regex or `translate()` in that it tests whether the string evaluates to a numeric value, whereas the other solutions would choke on, say, an exponential expression like `1.234E+10`. Or might pass an IP address like `127.0.0.1`.

[Here's a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a80a1f96a73f3a138d83c3fb565cd5d0).

If you have an earlier version of Oracle you can write a user-defined function which uses `to_number()` to evaluate a passed parameter:

```
create or replace function is_number (p_str in varchar2) return pls_integer
is
  rv pls_integer;
begin

  declare
    n number;
  begin

    n := to_number(p_str);
    rv := 1; -- p_str is a number

  exception
    when others then
      rv := 0; -- p_str is not a number
  end;

  return rv;

end;
/
```

You would call this function in the WHERE clause same as  `validate_conversion()` in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't use regex, for some reason:

```
SELECT COL
FROM SAMP_TAB
WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(COL, '0123456789', ' ')) IS NULL;
```

If you can use regex, then use `REGEXP_LIKE` with the pattern `^[0-9]+$`:

```
SELECT COL
FROM SAMP_TAB
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (COL, '^[0-9]+$');
```

### Demo

Comment: The OP said "without using any reg-exp".

Comment: That requirement seems fishy to me.  Why wouldn't the OP want to use regex, since this is the best way to handle this requirement (unless it's a homework question, etc.) ?

Comment: See @APC's answer below. As to "fishy" - I think "homework" explains it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234'  from dual union all
  3     select 'abcd'  from dual union all
  4     select '098'   from dual union all
  5     select '12wer' from dual union all
  6     select '1ab3'  from dual union all
  7     select '345'   from dual
  8    )
  9  select col
 10  from test
 11  where translate(col, 'a0123456789', 'a') is null;

COL
-----
1234
098
345

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting each character, extracting integers through filtering by `ascii()` function as 
`ascii(<character>) between 48 and 57`, and recombining the strings might be another option :

```
with t as
(      
 select substr(col,level,1) as chr, level as lvl,
        row_number() over (order by 0) as rn
   from samp_tab
  connect by level <= length(col)
      and prior sys_guid() is not null
      and prior col = col
), t2 as
(
select t.*, sum(case when lvl=1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rn) as rn2 
  from t
 where ascii(chr) between 48 and 57
)
select listagg(chr) within group (order by rn2) as new_col
  from t2
 group by rn2;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fb4379a7ef2e0520d02ba06e6c90ceea)</kbd>